# Unable to pass props to component through navigationOptions?

Tags: react-native

Based on [the docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/header-buttons.html) for React Navigation, this should be do-able! But I'm trying to figure out what is wrong in my setup.

Whenever I try to pass a prop through the navigation options, the child component can't see it.

My code:

```
import AddAlarm from '../components/AddAlarm';

export default class AlarmsScreen extends React.Component {

  static navigationOptions = {
    headerTitle: 'Alarms',
    headerLeft: <EditAlarms />,
    headerRight: (
      <AddAlarm propsTest="value" />
    ),
  };

  // ...

}
```

And in the  component:

```
export default class AddAlarm extends React.Component {

    handleAlarmAdd() {
        console.log( this.props.propsTest );
    }

    // ...

}
```

This throws an error that the expected prop isn't found. I've even tried to just log the props object itself, and I get "undefined".

I'm using Expo and running this in the iOS simulator. Props passed in normal context (through render()'s return) work just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you verify the value of `this` in `handleAlarmAdd`? It'd likely that you need to write `handleAlarmAdd = () => {...}`

Comment: That was it! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your fragment code seems to be right. I would like to check how you are calling `handleAlarmAdd` function because if you don´t want to declare it as arrow function or bind it in constructor you have to call it like this example: `onPress={() =>{this.handleAlarmAdd()}}`.

Answer (score 0):

The navigation properties can be passes using
**this.props.navigation.navigate('ScreenName',{  propsTest: "Test"});**

In the constructor of the navigated screen please access it using
**props.navigation.state.propsTest**